# Is it possible to loop scroll content embedded through iframe?

Tags: iframe, scroll, autoscroll

I have two iframes next to each other that display two different html files. Both iframes have a height of 500px.
Is it possible to have the iframe auto scroll from top to bottom and then jump back to top and scroll to bottom and so on. The user cannot scroll...

I cannot add code to the external html files as they are generated by a program. So I am wondering if there is a way to make the content of the iframe automatically scroll in an infinite loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to find a solution online, but they usually only work with divs not with iframes.